# Multiplying matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix M[1,98] and a matrix N[1,x], let's assume in this case x =16.
What I want is to multiply N by M , make the sum by element, and increment the matrix M. With the finality of getting an output of [1,98].

It's a bit confusing. An example:

```
M=[2 3 4 5 6 7]
N=[1 2 3]

it1=(2*1)+(3*2)+(4*3)+(5*0)+...=20
it2=(3*1)+(4*2)+(5*3)+(6*0)+...=26
it3=..

Output=[20 26 ... ... ... ...]
```

Like that until the end but considering the size of the matrix N variable. M has always the same size.

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm. What happens when you approach the edge of `M`, like the 5th iteration where there is nothing to multiply by `N(3)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution):

```
result = conv(M, N(end:-1:1), 'valid');
```

To achieve the result you want you need to flip the second vector and keep only the "valid" part of the convolution (no border effects).

In your example:

```
>> M = [2 3 4 5 6 7];
>> N = [1 2 3];
>> result = conv(M, N(end:-1:1), 'valid')
result =
    20    26    32    38
```

Comment: I guess he doesn't believe his own requirements ;)

Comment: @excaza Yes, output size should be smaller than input size :-)